# Como personalizar regra de validação para usuário com vários níveis de acesso?

Tags: php, laravel-5, validação

Eu preciso fazer uma validação no cadastro de usuário onde um e-mail só pode ser validado se na tabela `users` o seu nível de acesso, não seja de nível empresa. 
Na tabela `users`, já existe um campo chamado `nivel` que classifica esse tipo de nível dos usuários.

Lembrando que minha aplicação está escrita em `Laravel` 5.6.

Até o momento tenho essa validação:

```
$validate = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|min:3',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'phone' => 'required'
]);
```

Acredito que para essa situação eu preciso fazer uma regra personalizada mais ainda não tenho o conhecimento necessário.

Desde já eu agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Indico você estudar ACL que fica muito mais fácil de entender isso, mas caso queira usar dessas formas indico entender os Gates com ele você vai definir quem pode ver ou não pode ver.

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo usando seu código como nível, você vai em providers e AuthServiceProviders e no boot coloca:

```
public function boot(){

   Gate::define('Admin', function(User $user){
     return $user->nivel === "Admin"; //Valida se é Admin ou oque for criar
   } );
}
```

No controller irá usar da seguinte forma:

```
public function index(){

     if(Gate::allows('Admin')){
         return true; //Caso tenha permissão Admin
     }

     return false; //Caso não tenha permissão Admin

}
```

OBS: Não esqueça de dar use Gate no controller e no AuthServiceProvider e também não esqueça de dar use App\User para poder pegar o usuário logado.

Espero ter te ajudado qualquer dúvida só comentar!.

Referência: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#gates

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar uma solução...
A ideia que eu tive foi essa:

1. Criar um `FormRequest`
2. Definir as regras de validação para cada campo do formulário.
3. Criar uma `Rule` específica para validar o e-mail.
4. Chamar essa `Rule` nas regras de validação do `FormRequest`.

**Codigo**

*Controller*

```
public function storeUsuarioEmpresa(UsuarioEmpresaRequest $request)
{
    ...
}
```

*app/Requests/UsuarioEmpresaRequest.php*

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'phone' => 'required',
    ];

    $rules['email'] = ['required', 'email', 'max:100', new UsuarioEmpresaRule($this->email)];

    return $rules;
}
```

*app/Rules/UsuarioEmpresaRule.php*

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $user = Usuarios::getByEmail($this->email);
    if (empty($user)) {
        return true;
    }
    return $user->nivel != 2;
}

public function message()
{
    return 'Este e-mail já está cadastrado!';
}
```

Dessa forma eu consegui chegar no meu objetivo.

Comentem ai o que acharam ou sugestão de melhoria.

Valeu!